# How to add CSS reference link to local HTML files in folder?

Tags: c#, html, css, console-application

I have a folder named "DocSamples" on the file system, this folder has 100 HTML files and one cascading style sheet file named "docStyle.css", i want to add a reference to this style sheet `<link rel="stylesheet" href="docStyle.css">`to each HTML file in the folder using Console Application (C#).

Any idea on how I can implement this?

Thank you,

Comment: Hello Mohammad, I suggest using a filereader and loop over each file. Then, for each file you do a string filetext = File.ReadAllText(fileName);. And then do a filetext.replace("</head>", "<link rel="stylesheet" href="docStyle.css"></head>"). And of course save the file afterwards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like:

```
// Get all files
string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath("Filepath here");
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

//Handle each file
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.html"))

    // Get all text from 1 file
    string readText = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
    // Add css
    readText = readText.Replace("</head>", @"<link rel="stylesheet" href="docStyle.css"></head>")

    // Save file with modifications
    File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, readText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dieter for your response, much appreciated, i edited your code and used the below code, and it's working fine

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] htmlFiles = Directory.GetFiles("systemDrive\\Doc samples", "*.html");


//Handle each file
foreach (var htmlFile in htmlFiles)
{
    // Get all text from 1 file
    string readText = File.ReadAllText(htmlFile);
    // Add css
    readText = readText.Replace("</head>", @"<link rel='stylesheet' href='docStyle.css'></head>");

    // Save file with modifications
    File.WriteAllText(htmlFile, readText);
}
        }
```

Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.
Just be aware that you can't run it twice on the same file, else you'll be referencing the css twice.